# Checking if a Set of items exist in database quickly

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I have an external service which I'm grabbing a list of items from, and persisting locally a relationship between those items and a user. I feed that external service a name, and get back the associated items with that name. I am choosing to persist them locally because I'd like to keep my own attributes about those external items once they've been discovered by my application. The items themselves are pretty static objects, but the total number of them are unknown to me, and the only time I learn about new ones is if a new user has an association with them on the external service.

When I get a list of them back from the external service, I want to check if they exist in my database first, and use that object instead but if it doesn't I need to add them so I can set my own attributes and keep the association to my user.

Right now I have the following (pseudocode, since it's broken into service layers etc):

```
Set<ExternalItem> items = externalService.getItemsForUser(user.name);
for (ExternalItem externalItem : items){
    Item dbItem = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Item.class,item.id);
    if (dbitem == null){
        //Not in database, create it.
        dbItem = mapToItem(externalItem);
    } 
    user.addItem(dbItem);

}
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);//Saves the associated Items also.
```

The time this operation is taking is around 16 seconds for approximately 500 external items. The remote operation is around 1 second of that, and the save is negligible also. The drain that I'm noticing comes from the numerous `session.get(Item.class,item.id)` calls I'm doing.

Is there a better way to check for an existing Item in my database than this, given that I get a Set back from my external service?

Note: The external item's id is reliable to be the same as mine, and a single id will always represent the same External Item

Comment: If you dont want to add another data structure (filter) the only thing I can imagine would help is to reduce the round trips to the database (and to make sure there is an index on the itemID). Round trips would be reduced by using a native SQL query with a IN(id1, id2, id3) construct. Unfortunatelly I think this needs to be done manually by constructing equal-sized prepared statements with multiple arguments. (keep the number of variation smalls).

Comment: @eckes So I guess I would batch them into groups of 20 or so, do a native select where id in (id1,id2,...,id20) and then investigate the returned structure for what ids of that original list are returned.

Comment: Yes, so 110 results would be 15 roundtrips (5 x 20 + 10 x 1) with only 2 different statements to parse.  Or you can have 100,10 and 1 depending on the range of number of items typically checked. I am not sure if Hibernate has an helper for this.

Comment: BTW: you could also save processing on the ORM layer if you do not request the `Item` object (or only lazyly load it) so the SQL statement will only return the ItemID (string) column not all columns. (or if you do not batch, then just return the count).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely recommend a native query, as recommended in the comments.

I would not bother to chunk them, though, given the numbers you are talking about. *Postgres* should be able to handle an `IN` clause with 500 elements with no problems. I have had programmatically generated queries with many more items than that which performed fine.

This way you also have only one round trip, which, assuming the proper indexes are in place, really should complete in sub-second time.

Comment: I did it this way, iterating over the external ids, adding them to a set and then querying `select * from items where id in (...)` and returning a list of ids that matched. I then iterated over the original set of external items again, and for every one that was in the resultset, i did a `session.load()` and for every one that wasn't in the resultset I created new and saved everything afterwards. The operation is now 2-3 seconds long, which is much more reasonable for a webapp.